one of my question was deleted
on Sep 28 '18 this question was removed (Which branches of mathematics are most important to understand cryptography?) without any reason, notification, there was not even an email that clarifies why this happened. 
I was well-received attention has that 65 point score.
recently I sent an email to support and they mentioned this question is better to ask in Meta.
My question is why: that question is removed and why there was no notification?    

For reference for our 10k users: This is the question that is being asked about here.


without any reason, notification, there was not even an email that clarifies why this happened

Reason
There is a reason indicated on the question itself:

merged by e-sushi Sep 28 '18 at 23:18
This question was merged with Current mathematics theory used in cryptography/coding theory because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

This was a clear duplicate of another question, and was closed as such. It received agreement as such by the community, and a deciding vote by our former moderator e-sushi closed it.
Notification
As far as a notification, I don't know how to confirm or deny whether or not one was sent to you.
Typically, when something happens with a question, such as someone editing it, it receives an answer, someone comments, etc, a notification ends up in your inbox. I have never had a question closed as a duplicate, so I don't know first-hand whether or not this should generate a notification. I expect it does generate a notification.
Email
As far as email is concerned: You can control your own email settings by clicking on your user icon, navigating to edit profile and setting, and clicking on the Edit email settings link. You can control how frequently stackexchange will email you about unread items in your notifications inbox.

Thank you for your answer, but there was no notification to make it clear for me.

Note that a merge is even stronger than a normal duplicate vote and cannot be reverted and will also transfer comments and answers from the "duplicate" to the "original"

Your question was merged and subsequently deleted in favor of "an exact duplicate", which is shown here. This action was taken by one of the previous mods, so I cannot really discuss particular issues about it.
If you have any specific questions that are not answered by the question after the merge then don't hesitate to ask a new question, but please be specific and try to have minimum of overlap with the other question.

Thank you for your answer.
